# Proof that $E[\exp(|A|)] \leq \exp(\delta) + \exp(\delta)P(|A|>\delta) + \int_\delta^\infty\exp(x)P(|A|>x)dx$

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $A$ be a random variable and $P$ be a probability measure. For some real $\delta>0$, is there a simple proof that $E[\exp(|A|)] \leq \exp(\delta) + \exp(\delta)P(|A|>\delta) + \int_\delta^\infty\exp(x)P(|A|>x)dx$?

This statement was written as obvious by [Capitaine](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01213388), page 196 and [Ikeda and Watanabe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444861726) page 450, but I've failed to get any progress in understanding it. Capitaine says it follows from Fubini's theorem. I think it is not necessary to assume that $A$ admits a density.

Comment: Do you mean "is there a simple proof that this holds for some real $\delta$?" or "for some real $\delta$, there is a simple proof of this," as for the latter, I can pick a $\delta = 0$, and perhaps give a simple proof.

Comment: Well, I ideally want a proof (simple or not) that holds for every $\delta$, but if you have a proof for $\delta=0$ it's a good start, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}e^{|A|} &= \int 1_{\{|A| \leq \delta\}} \underbrace{e^{|A|}}_{\leq e^{\delta}} \, d\mathbb{P} + \int 1_{\{|A|> \delta\}} \cdot e^{|A|} \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &\leq \underbrace{e^{\delta} \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A| \leq \delta) + e^{\delta} \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A|>\delta)}_{=e^{\delta} \leq e^{\delta}+e^{\delta} \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A|>\delta)} + \int 1_{\{|A|> \delta\}} \cdot (e^{|A|}-e^{\delta}) \, d\mathbb{P} \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

Now note that

$$\begin{align*} \int_{\delta}^{\infty} e^x \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A|>x) \, dx &= \mathbb{E} \left( \int_{\delta}^{\infty} e^x \cdot 1_{\{|A|>x\}} \, dx \right) \tag{2} \end{align*}$$

by Fubini's theorem where

$$\begin{align*} \int_{\delta}^{\infty} e^x \cdot 1_{\{|A|>x\}} \, dx &= \begin{cases} \int_{\delta}^{|A|} e^x \, dx = e^{|A|}-e^{\delta} & |A|>\delta \\ 0 & |A| \leq \delta \end{cases} \\ &= (e^{|A|}-e^{\delta}) \cdot 1_{\{|A|>\delta\}} \tag{3} \end{align*}$$

Therefore, the claim follows by combining (1)-(3).

Comment: From the first line of Eq. (1) to the second we are being conservative, right? The inequality would be more tight with $E[e^{|A|}]\leq e^\delta + \int_\delta^\infty e^x P(|A|>x) dx$.

Comment: @Dimas The first line of Eq. (1) equals (!) $$e^{\delta} \mathbb{P}(|A| \leq \delta) + e^{\delta} \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A|>\delta) + \int 1_{\{|A|>\delta\}} \cdot (e^{|A|}-e^{\delta}) \, d\mathbb{P}$$ so we only used the estimate $\mathbb{P}(|A| \leq \delta) \leq 1$ to get the second line of (1). Of course the inequality $\mathbb{E}e^{|A|} \leq e^{\delta} + \int_{\delta}^{\infty} e^x \mathbb{P}(|A|>x) \, dx$ would be more tight, but does not hold in general, as far as I can see.

Comment: @saz The last inequality in your comment does hold since the integral is $E((e^{|A|}-e^\delta)^+)$, and $E(Z^+)\geqslant E(Z)$.

Comment: @Did Ah, you are right, of course - nice way to prove it. Actually, the inequality is also a simple consequence of my own proof since obviously $$e^{\delta}\cdot \mathbb{P}(|A| \leq \delta) + e^{\delta} \cdot \mathbb{P}(|A|>\delta) = e^{\delta}.$$